How do I create a Vertex AI Pipeline with the gcloud CLI?
As part of a CI/CD pipeline, I'd like to automatically deploy or update Vertex AI pipelines. However, I couldn't figure out how to create a Vertex AI pipeline with the gcloud CLI-tool.
Using the Python SDK I have two files: one in which the pipeline is defined and compiled (vertex_pipeline.py), and another one (submit_to_vertex.py) in which the compiled pipeline (greet_pipeline.json) is used to create or submit the pipeline to Vertex AI.
These files look as follows:
# vertex_pipeline.py
from kfp import dsl
from kfp.compile import Compiler

@dsl.component(base_image=IMAGE)
def greet(name: str):
    print(f"Hi {name=}. How are you today?")

@dsl.pipeline(name="greet_pipeline"):
def greet_pipeline(people_to_greet: str = "Tom"):
    greet_task=greet(name=people_to_greet)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Compiler().compile(pipeline_func=greet_pipeline, package_path="greet_pipeline.json")


# submit_to_vertex.py
import google.cloud.aiplatform as aiplatform

PROJECT_ID=...
LOCATION=...
...

aiplatform.init(project=PROJECT_ID,location=LOCATION)

pipeline_=aiplatform.pipeline_jobs.PipelineJob(...)
pipeline_.submit(service_account=SERVICE_ACCOUNT)

What is the equivalent of the second file with gcloud? I've read the documentation of gcloud but couldn't find anything related.

I don't know the answer. gcloud doesn't always provide functional equivalence to the APIs|SDKs and it's possible this functionality is not present in gcloud. Why can you not use the Python scripts in your CI/CD pipeline?

Using Python at this step significantly complicates the process. I'm utilizing cloud build to execute the CI/CD pipeline. Although there is a gcloud cloud builder (a predefined image with gcloud installed), a python cloud builder is not available. Creating custom cloud builders is possible, but this introduces several additional steps, increasing the complexity and potential failure points.

Additionally, and this might be just my personal preference, using Python to manage Vertex AI feels odd because most other services can be managed using gcloud, but not with python.

Indeed, it would be good if gcloud included the functionality but, assuming it doesn't, you need to find an alternative. Since you'd be using Python with the SDK to implement the equivalent to gcloud functionality, you don't need a gcloud builder for this step; you can just use any container that will run your Python code.

Hi @bayes2021 , currently to create a Vertex AI Pipeline with the gcloud CLI is not possible , you can use  Python with the SDK for that.  If you want to use gcloud CLI to create pipeline , you can open a new Feature request  as per requirements on the public issue tracker describing your issue and Eng team will look on the issue for future implementation . Let me know if this helps or not .

As of today (2024-09-19) gcloud doesn't have this functionality.
However you could use pure API to perform such things (see orginal example Using the Pipelines REST API):
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/bb2c8c502d281f49fb5b5fa2a40fada0c8b66144/notebooks/official/pipelines/pipelines_intro_kfp.ipynb
